# Maui Android RuntimeIdentifiers and SelfContained

Tags: xamarin.android, maui

Im very lost with this, try different solutions i search here and nothing works. I published the first apk version a week ago, but when i run visual studio today, it doesn't build.

EveryTime i build the app output gives -> "**NETSDK1031 It is not supported to build or publish a self-contained application without specifying a RuntimeIdentifier. You must either specify a RuntimeIdentifier or set SelfContained to false.**"

Also if someone could explain me, to understand whats happening, appreciate it.

My .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst;net6.0-android31.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>AppRipsaPagosMAUI</RootNamespace>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

    <!-- App Identifier -->
    <ApplicationId>com.companyname.appripsapagosmaui</ApplicationId>
    <ApplicationIdGuid>61252DD6-68C5-4051-9E5F-30226AFF9A7E</ApplicationIdGuid>

    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">14.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Did you publish your android application? Now you want to debug your application in VS, am I right? Please try to change `net6.0-android31.0` to `net6.0-android` in `<TargetFrameworks>` tag.

Comment: Yes @LeonLu-MSFT i published and when try to debug that error happened. After changing that, it solved my problem. Also remove bin and obj folders, clean + rebuild + maui-check with package manager console with maui-check library! if you want post it as an answer!

Comment: I post it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to change `net6.0-android31.0` to `net6.0-android` in `<TargetFrameworks>` tag. And remove `bin` and `obj` folders, clean + rebuild + maui-check with package manager console with maui-check library